# Access code is causing program to lock up and not responding?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I copied this code from a differen website to try and help me import multiple text files at once.  I changed filepaths, text specs, and the table to what I need.  Now every time I try to run this is locks up and doesn't respond.

Is there an issue with having too many text files or too much data?  How come its causing my program to lock up?

```
Public Sub WorkedAlertsImport()
On Error GoTo bImportFiles_Click_Err

Dim objFS As Object, objFolder As Object
Dim objFiles As Object, objF1 As Object
Dim strFolderPath As String

strFolderPath = "C:\Import TXT files\"
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolderPath)
Set objFiles = objFolder.files

For Each objF1 In objFiles
    If Right(objF1.Name, 3) = "txt" Then
        DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "TextImportSpecs", "tblImportedFiles", strFolderPath & objF1.Name, False
        Name strFolderPath & objF1.Name As "C:\Import TXT files\" & objF1.Name 'Move the files to the archive folder
    End If
Next

Set objF1 = Nothing
Set objFiles = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFS = Nothing

bImportFiles_Click_Exit:
Exit Sub

bImportFiles_Click_Err:
MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
Resume bImportFiles_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a cursory review of your code, I see no reason why it would cause MS Access to lock up, which would typically be caused by code executing a loop which never met a terminating condition (however, a `For Each` loop is iterating over a fixed set of data and will therefore always terminate).

I would note that the following line is redundant:

```
Name strFolderPath & objF1.Name As "C:\Import TXT files\" & objF1.Name
```

Since earlier in the code you define `strFolderPath` as:

```
strFolderPath = "C:\Import TXT files\"
```

Hence, you are renaming the file to itself.

The code is also naïvely testing the last three characters of the filename, which may not necessarily yield an extension if you were to encounter a file without an extension.

---

The code could be written without using the FSO and without the `if` statement altogether, as VBA offers the [`Dir`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dir-function-1a1a4275-f92f-4ae4-8b87-41e4513bba2e) function as standard to iterate over files of a particular type in a directory, e.g.:

```
Sub test()
    Dim strDir As String: strDir = "C:\Import TXT files"
    Dim strTxt As String: strTxt = Dir(strDir & "\*.txt")

    Do Until strTxt = vbNullString
        DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "TextImportSpecs", "tblImportedFiles", strDir & "\" & strTxt, False
        strTxt = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: The [`Name` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-statement) actually has the side effect of physically renaming/moving a file on disk -- I doubt it's redundant.

Comment: Even though the filepath on either side of the `As` is identical?

Comment: Oh, the `"C:\Import TXT files\"` string literal is redundant / should be referring to `strFolderPath` - but the instruction itself is side-effecting. Wait, what? :facepalm: missed the forest for the tree, sorry

Comment: No worries Mathieu - I've reworded my answer slightly.

Comment: That worked MUCH better.  It was still locking up when it was importing but it actually completed everything this time.

Comment: @MyNameHere Are the text files particularly large?

Comment: @LeeMac They're not large in the sense of disk size, but they each have 800-1500 rows.

Comment: @MyNameHere If there are many files, perhaps add `DoEvents` after the `DoCmd` line as this will momentarily pass control back to the OS and should avoid the "not responding" warning you receive if the OS does not receive feedback from the application in 5 seconds.